# Github scraping for all javascript files

Tags: python, rest, github, web-scraping, github-api

I need to extract all available javascript files over all the projects available on github using python.I looked for an API in github and I found this : 
https://developer.github.com/v3/
I don't understand what kind of requests do I  have to send and how do I compose the URL.I would prefer not depending on another 3rd party API if possible.
Please guide me in the right direction,Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: That's going to take weeks https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting

Comment: I could use different auths...Even if it takes time I have to do it...Is there a way around? And I dont understand how do i compose the URL...I am not familiar with curl

Comment: Are you looking to do this for a single organization/user; or all users on GitHub?

Comment: All users , the more the better...

Comment: Voting to close as *too broad* because `Please guide me` is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gather the files you can use this in your python script:

```
import os 
os.system("curl -o https://github.com/file.js")
```

Replace the URL with the individual file name, or in your case a variable in your loop to grab all files from a repo. You will need to repeat this for each org/user/repo/etc

[Download remote files using curl](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/13/download-with-curl/)

[Running shell commands from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Thanks!!!!I'll try it out....Sorry for being unable to upvote,my reputation is quite low...